# Git auto update prompting for old version

Tags: windows, git, updates

```
C:\Users\phill>git --version
git version 2.19.2.windows.1

C:\Users\phill>git.exe update-git-for-windows
Git for Windows 2.19.2.windows.1 (64bit)
Update 2.19.1.windows.1 is available
Download and install Git for Windows 2.19.1 [N/y]? n
```

As per the cmd output I have already updated to git version 2.19.2 yesterday.
However git is now prompting to reinstall 2.19.1??

This happens every damn time there's a git update and it's begining to be very annoying.

I'd like not to have to disable the auto update checks if at all posible.
Is there any other fix for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your version

https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.19.2.windows.1

it is marked as pre-release "because of two major breakages". 
At this moment 2.19.2 might be a "bleeding edge" perhaps?

There is a known bug in git for windows https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1843 related to release candidates and the automatic updates option you are using.

Comment: It's just annoying that it prompted me to update yesterday and now it's prompting me to downgrade. Perhaps the only answer is to disable automatic update.